# Testing maps with Starcraft 2 starter edition

Tags: starcraft-2

I have a friend who wants to work on a SC2 custom map, and I figured I'd help him out since I loved playing around with the old Warcraft editor. Blizzard's take on starter edition users using the map maker seems to be "do it, just don't expect an easy test button or publishing." However I can't seem to find any other way to test custom maps. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What exactly is your question the process of creating a custom map in the editor is far more complicated the an answer here can explain

Comment: I meant is there any way to start the map within starcraft 2 without using the "Test Map" button.

Comment: No there isn't...

Comment: Pretty much what Ramhound said.  There is no way to test maps made in the editor because in order to run the physics, AI, and everything else associated with the map, you need to be running the game.